# Subtrair data com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Tenho o seguinte problema, tenho uma data que vem do banco e comparo com a data atual, e faço o seguinte:

```
var dataAtual = new Date();
var partesData = dataAtual.split("/");
var dataAtualNova = new Date(partesData[2], partesData[1] - 1, partesData[0]);
var dataassinado = new Date({vem do banco});

if(dataAtualNova < dataassinado){ //faça algo }
```

Porem a data atual fica por exemplo `17/05/1995` e data que vem do banco vem `17/05/1995 10:45` então se as datas forem iguais a data que vem do banco sempre será maior que a data atual por causa das horas, como posso igualar ou tirar as horas?

Comment: Amigão, já pensou em usar [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)? Talvez saia mais em conta utilizá-lo.

Comment: Legal amigo, mas para este problema gostaria de utilizar jquery ou js puro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando apenas javascript

- Use o método [Date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp) - passando zero para o construtor para zerar as horas
- Para comparar as datas, use o método [Date.getTime()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) que retornará um inteiro com o total de milisegundos da data.

```js
var data1 = new Date(2016, 11, 1, 16, 15, 30); // 01/12/2016 16:15:30
var data2 = new Date(2016, 11, 1); // 01/12/2016 00:00:00

console.log('Comparando com as horas, elas são diferentes:');
console.log(data1.getTime() === data2.getTime());

data1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

console.log('Sem as horas, são iguais.');
console.log(data1.getTime() === data2.getTime());
```

Comment: Isso que eu precisava, obrigado :)

Answer (score 2):

Se a data que você possui está nesse formato `17/05/1995 10:45`, você pode separar pelo espaço e pegar somente a data:

```
var somenteData = "17/05/1995 10:45".split(" ")[0]; // 17/05/1995 10:45 > 17/05/1995
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, o comando data1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) do amigo acima me satisfez